# Check and Add a document to the Firestore database (swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

first I want to check if a doc with the Uid of the user is already created and if not, it should create a doc with the Uid of the user as a title.

Here is my code: (Somehow it doesnt work)

It gives me the error: Value of type 'CollectionReference' has no member 'doc'

```
@IBAction func GoogleSignIn(_ sender: Any) {

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)

        let user: GIDGoogleUser = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()!.currentUser

        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let email = user.profile.email

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document {


                if document.exists{
                    print("User already in Database")

                } else {

                print("User needs to get signed into Database")

                    db.collection("users").doc(uid).set([
                        "fullname" : fullName,
                        "email": email
                    ])


                }

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

is ".doc" a method? Don't you want `db.collection("users").document(uid)`